# Publishing to GitHub Actions Marketplace - "you'll see a banner" - I don't see any banner

Tags: github, dockerfile, github-actions

In the GitHub documentation here:

It says:

> When a repository contains an action metadata file (action.yml or
> action.yaml), you'll see a banner to publish the action to GitHub
> Marketplace. Click Draft a release.

It also says:

> Actions are published to GitHub Marketplace immediately and aren't
> reviewed by GitHub as long as they meet these requirements:
>
> - The action must be in a public repository.
> - Each repository must contain a single action.
> - The action's metadata file (action.yml or action.yaml) must be in the root directory of the repository.
> - The name in the action's metadata file must be unique.
>
>   - The name cannot match an existing action name published on GitHub Marketplace.
>   - The name cannot match a user or organization on GitHub, unless the user or organization owner is publishing the action. For example, only the GitHub organization can publish an action named github. The name cannot match an existing GitHub Marketplace category. GitHub reserves the names of GitHub features.

This repository I've created: https://github.com/jhudsl/ottr-reports meets all these requirements as far as I've been able to tell, but I still don't see any supposed banner appear.

They make it sound so simple, but I haven't seen that banner show up no matter what things I've tried altering. Is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: According to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace you have to tick a box named *Publish this action to the GitHub Marketplace* when publishing the release. Did you do that?

Comment: I had tried to make a release as well (the tick box didn't show up). Honestly I don't think I changed anything but the Marketplace banner finally showed today. Maybe it was a GitHub server glitch? I don't really know but I was finally able to see the banner and publish.

Comment: Hi, @cansavvy how long did you get the banner after you made the last commit?